# How to create a Dreamweaver extension?

Tags: documentation, dreamweaver

I don't know how to say this, but is it me or there isn't a dedicated tutorial on how to make an extension, all I ever got was a PDF saying how to make one, but there is not documentation on how to create one...

The online PDF link is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Dreamweaver/10.0_Extending/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d117f508c8de-7fde.html).

I'm intrigued on creating Dreamweaver extensions. I have Dreamweaver CS5.

Answer (score 0):

True, the Adobe documentation on extensions creation is very slim, especially if you are looking at the latest releases. What I think you should do is to look back to the origins.

First of all the SDK offers great examples (from 2003):
http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1009962

Also there are two great books: Dreamweaver MX Extensions by Laura Gutman and Building Dreamweaver 4 & UltraDev 4 Extensions by Tom Muck and Ray West. I believe you may read free chapters online in places such Safari library or Google books.

The books are old, you have to understand and adapt for the new versions, but in essence everything stays the same.